# How to create a program white list for a new user account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have two user accounts on my PC, one is administrator and the other standard user. The standard user account is for my son. I am wondering how do I create a white list where I can choose the programs he is allowed to execute.

For example, some of (but not all) the programs I will only be wanting him to open are the Microsoft Office suite programs, google chrome and Skype e.t.c.

How am I able to set this white list or something similar from my administrator account, or do I have to set those rules while logged into standard account?

I am using windows 7 pro x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This process uses Local Group Policy Editor which is not available in Home versions of Windows 7 or 8.

First click on Start and enter gpedit.msc into the search box and hit Enter.

Navigate to User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ System. Then under Setting scroll down and double click on Run only specified Windows applications.

Set it to Enabled, then under the Options section click on the Show button next to List of allowed applications.

A Show Contents dialog comes up where you can type in the apps you want to allow users to run. When finished with the list, click OK then close out of Local Group Policy Editor.

If a user tries to access an application that is not on the specified list they will receive the following error message.

If you need screenshots to assist you [How-To-Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/) has them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link provided. It has completely solved my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parental controls:
http://www.ampercent.com/how-to-setup-parental-controls-in-windows-7-restrict-computer-and-internet-usage-of-your-kids/6713/

You can start it by typing in "Parental Controls" in your Start Menu.
The specific option is called "Allow or Block specific programs" where you can tick the programs you want them to use.

Comment: You should include the steps in your answer. If that link goes down in the future, your answer doesn't provide much help when another user comes accross this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I added ticking the programs. I can't add more, that's literally all it takes :)